# Whole page get refreshed while using Pagination?

Tags: liferay-6

I am using to show my results in pagination. But when pressed next or previous  tag it causes refresh of entire page which I dont want .How to prevent the page refresh?

Comment: you are using .. what ? do you mean a '<liferay-ui:search-container>' ? You should tell us the component you're working with

Answer (score 0):

use ajax pagination methods instead of normal pagination

Comment: what are the ajax pagination methods ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0" prefix="portlet"%>
 <%@ taglib uri="http://liferay.com/tld/ui" prefix="liferay-ui"%>
 <%@ taglib uri="http://liferay.com/tld/aui" prefix="aui" %>
 <%@ page import="java.util.List"%>
 <%@ page import="java.util.ArrayList" %>
 <%@ page import="com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.ListUtil"%>
 <%@ page import="com.liferay.portal.service.UserLocalServiceUtil"%>
 <%@ page import="com.liferay.portal.model.User"%>
 <%@ page import="com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.LiferayWindowState" %>
 <%@ page import="javax.portlet.PortletURL"%>
 <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<portlet:defineObjects />
<liferay-theme:defineObjects />

<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"%>
<%
    List<User> empList = new ArrayList<User>();
    empList.addAll(UserLocalServiceUtil.getUsers(0,
            UserLocalServiceUtil.getUsersCount()));
%>
<%
PortletURL renderURL = renderResponse.createRenderURL();
renderURL.setWindowState(LiferayWindowState.NORMAL);
renderURL.setParameter("jspPage","/html/userpagination/view.jsp"); 

%>
<liferay-ui:search-container delta="10" iteratorURL="<%= renderURL %>" emptyResultsMessage="empty-users" >

<liferay-ui:search-container-results>

<% 
results=ListUtil.subList(empList,searchContainer.getStart(),searchContainer.getEnd());
total = empList.size();
pageContext.setAttribute("results", results);
pageContext.setAttribute("total", total);
%>

</liferay-ui:search-container-results> 
    <div class="taglib-search-iterator-page-iterator-bottom"
        id="<portlet:namespace />searchUsers">
        <liferay-ui:search-container-row
            className="com.liferay.portal.model.User" keyProperty="userId"
            modelVar="user">

            <liferay-ui:search-container-column-text name="Name"
                value="<%=user.getScreenName()%>" />

        </liferay-ui:search-container-row>
        <liferay-ui:search-iterator searchContainer="<%=searchContainer%>"
            paginate="<%=false%>" />

        <c:if test="<%=results.size() > 0%>">


            <liferay-ui:search-paginator searchContainer="<%=searchContainer%>"
                type="article" />


        </c:if>
    </div>
</liferay-ui:search-container>

<aui:script use="aui-io-plugin">
    var searchUsers = A.one('#<portlet:namespace />searchUsers');

    if (searchUsers) {
        var parent = searchUsers.get('parentNode');
        console.log(parent);

        parent.plug(
            A.Plugin.IO,
            {
                autoLoad: false
            }
        );

        searchUsers.all('a').on(
            'click',
            function(event) {
                var uri = event.currentTarget.get('href').replace(/p_p_state=normal/i, 'p_p_state=exclusive');

                parent.io.set('uri', uri);
                parent.io.start();

                event.preventDefault();
            }
        );
    }
</aui:script>
```

Answer (score 0):

THis is the normal behaviour for the liferay search container as it is not ajaxified by default.
You could try to set the window mode like this in your JSP:

```
<%
PortletURL portletURL = renderResponse.createRenderURL();
portletURL.setWindowState(WindowState.MAXIMIZED);
%>
```

Best regards,

Daniel